# Javascript - How to load content depends on url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 buttons and when we click it redirects to different pages with `window.location.replace` and in `document ready` I put 2 if's for each click button. But what happens is when I click it entry inside both if's and should not.

My click function:

```
$('a[href="#reception-supplier"]').on('click', function()
  {
    var type = $(this).attr('data-type');

    $.get("/reception-type/"+type, function(data)
    {
      $('.popup').html('');
      $('.popup').append(data);
      $('.popup').fadeIn(300);
      $('.loading').fadeOut(300);
      $('.inputDossie').select2();

      $('.enter-reception-order').on('click', function()
      {

        var supplierId = $('#supplierChoose option:selected').val();

        window.location.replace("/reception-order-header-supplier/"+supplierId);

      });
    });
  });
```

The second function click:

```
$('a[href="#reception-order"]').on('click', function()
  {
    $.get("/reception-type/"+type, function(data)
    {
      $('.popup').html('');
      $('.popup').append(data);
      $('.popup').fadeIn(300);
      $('.loading').fadeOut(300);
      $('.input-order').focus();

      $('.enter-reception-order').on('click', function()
      {
        $('.error-message-reception').fadeOut(300);
        $('.error-message-reception .error').remove();
        var orderId = $('.input-order').val();
        $.get("/verify-reception-order/"+orderId, function(validOrder)
        {
            window.location.replace("/reception-order-header/"+orderId);
        });

      });

    });
  });
```

And in `document ready` I put this 2 if's:

```
$(document ).ready(function()
 {
    if(window.location.href.match('/reception-order-header-supplier/?') !== null)
    {
      alert('1');
    }

    if(window.location.href.match('/reception-order-header/?') !== null)
    {
      alert('2');
     }
 });
```

How can I resolve this issue or what are the alternatives?

Thank you

Comment: isn't `.match` a sort of regex so using the / will mean it only searches for the text inside it - so *reception-order-header* will be found in both?  you could try escaping the slashes: `\/` and see if that works

Comment: you could convert the second if to an else if in case you dont want that condition to be checked when the first if is true

Comment: like this "/reception-order-header\/?" ? @Pete